# How to export HTML table into the excel format?

Tags: php, excel

I have an HTML table with colorful cells. The cell are coloured according  to the data coming from the database. I want to export the table in to the excel format with the same colors shown in the html table.?

The link of the table is:
http://teradata.eu.pn/index2.php?name=5

Comment: You can check this link..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291410/export-mysql-data-into-ms-excel-using-a-link-button-in-php

Answer (score 0):

[PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) has options to read a basic HTML file and write it as Excel OfficeOpenXML (xlsx) or BIFF (xls): the HTML Reader doesn't yet support more than rudimentary styling, but that can be added by a script